# Twentyeleven used post format

Tags: php, wordpress

I am developing a theme and using twentyeleven theme as my base theme

Twenty eleven uses `<?php get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() ); ?>`

To fetch post

SO  this codes work properly in index.php

But when i use in custom page template

it doesnt get fomratted propely

```
 <?php

/*
Template Name: Vote Page Template
*/


 get_header(); ?>

 <div id="primary">

 <div class="container">
 <head>

 </head>

        <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>



<?php /* Start the Loop */ ?>




            <?php while ( have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>



  <?php get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() ); ?>




            <?php endwhile; ?>

   <?php endif; ?>
  </div>
  </div>
  <?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Proper Format 
[image: This is a Proper FOrmat]

Unproper Format

[image]

Comment: Maybe in Your CSS You have classes that depends on a post or page class?
Use Chrome of Firefox Web Developer Tools and examine wrongly shpwn elements to check, if they have same css classes. If not, maybe Your's custom page template is missing a div or two with mandatory classes or id's. Without link to a wirking site, nobody wont be able to help You better ;)

Comment: They seem to work fine when i dont call my header and only include style sheet

Comment: That will not help much. As I said, check with inspector those elements and findout why css doesnt apply to them. Or post the site online, than someone will help.